# Ubuntu Cloudflare warp for teams not enrolling

Tags: ubuntu, cloudflare, cloudflare-warp

When i click Open Cloudflare WARP in my browser it opens a open with windows of ubuntu and there are no choices and there is just no apps available, i have cloudflare warp installed and it doesnt enroll to my linux machine. Windows machine works like a charm.

I have tried this multiple times and reinstalling warp.